# When the sum of two sins a constant for any odd n

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization, recreational-mathematics, alternative-proof

I'm trying to solve an interesting trig/optimisation problem that I've never seen before. Thought I'd reach out for inspiration.

I need to figure out a solution (value of x & y) to the below statment:

abs($sin(n* \pi*  x) + sin (n*\pi*y))  =K$, where K is a constant for any odd integer value of n.

Solution must satisfy:

abs($sin(1* \pi*  x) + sin (1*\pi*y))  =K$

abs($sin(3* \pi*  x) + sin (3*\pi*y))  =K$

abs($sin(5* \pi*  x) + sin (7*\pi*y))  =K$

If anyone has any ideas on where to start it would be much appreciated!

Ps. Once I've cracked this I will have to solve:
abs($sin(n* \pi*  x) + sin (n*\pi*y)) + sin (n*\pi*z))   =K'$

Comment: x=1 y=2n+1 give k=0  for example is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. K should be non 0. Something like  x = 1/4, y = 3/4 would be an example.

Comment: What is $z$ doing here ?

Comment: That's just an example of a more complicated case. Its not needed for the main question